# Name of this kind of design element?

Tags: page-layout

Maybe a dumb question, but is there a name for this kind of design element? Zoom, preview or something along those lines?

[image]

Comment: This is not a comment about your naming question but a remark about your example illustration: Since the enlarged detail is showing the entire screen of the phone, your "link" or "funnel" between the full photo and the phone screenshot should rather not end in one single point in the middle of the phone. It would be better if the "link"-start would show from where to where the detail view is taken. I.e. you could widen the link at its origin to make it entirely self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

In German I call this "Detailvergrößerung", so an English equivalent might be "view with detail magnification"; and there is no need for a cute "magnifying glass" to call it that.

Mind that "zoom" can be in or out so is not a precise name. And this element normally is not used for previews but to show more details of actual data or screen objects.

Comment: Thats a very clear answer - good points about zoom & preview.

Comment: In english engineering documents its usually called "detail view"

Comment: @alxmntrvl I've also seen  it called a "detail enlargement",  - but call it what you want!